# My Laptop is not allowing me to install new windows. I just forgot the BIOS password. Is there any assembly code or solution for the same?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I have set BIOS password few years ago. Now I forgot the password. While installing new Windows or formatting, it asks for the password. I don't know how to reset it. Is there any backdoor password for Lenovo-Z570. Or some assembly code or script. Removed CMOS battery but that didn't work.

Comment: CMOS won't work due to storing the BIOS password in a place where constant power isn't needed. As far as I know, there is no way to remove the SVP password without having Lenovo replace the board. I do believe there is someway to "short" out the board near the Memory Modules, but not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the Help! My research also says the same. Is there any backdoor password provided by Lenovo for such issues. Else there is no way i guess than replacing the board.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe Lenovo has let these password become public information in order to keep protection firm when enabling the SVP option.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way to restore access to your BIOS by reverse engineering checksums (not sure if it's a correct term). There is a [post](http://dogber1.blogspot.com.ee/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html) with a full description of the procedure you need to follow.

The basic idea is to get you BIOS to display the checksum by typing the incorrect password the maximum allowed number of times - 3. Then your BIOS should display the checksum which you input into [BIOS Master Password Creator for Laptops](https://bios-pw.org/).

Unfortunately I haven't tried it by myself, but there could be a chance that this can work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I didn't issue the downvote.  I would list the issues of I thought you would address them, but here I am, replying to your comment accusing me of a downvote I didn't even do.  Your comment is exactly the reason voting is annymous, to prevent users like you, abusing people who do issue a vote.